# Should we migrate all new software recommendations?

Tags: discussion

Recently I was made aware of a new Stack site in regards to software recommendations and I was curious if we should start migrating all **new** questions we see to the beta stack site [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The existence of Software Recommendations is by no means an obligation for any site to change its policy. The site was created because some sites, notably Stack Overflow and Super User, have a wide ban on questions that reduce to a software recommendation, even if they would be generally suitable for Stack Exchange. But other sites do allow software recommendation questions and have not and do not intend to stop doing so.

You should consider migrating questions away from Graphic Design only if they are off-topic on Graphic Design. Generally speaking, the best people to answer recommendations for software related to graphic design are the audience of Graphic Design.

If you consider a question for migration, please note that Software Recommendations has [quality requirements for questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [answers](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)). We close questions and delete answers that do not meet our guidelines. For questions, in a nutshell, we want both a user story (what will the software be used for?) and a set of minimal requirements.

Should software recommendations about graphic design be on SR or GD? It comes down to a choice:

- To get better answers, they should be on Graphic Design.
- To get assured moderation, they should be on Software Recommendations.

So I recommend making software recommendation questions off-topic here only if you cannot moderate them to enforce quality. If you find that you are inundated with poor quality questions (“what's the best image editor? title says all”) or poor quality answers (“ImageEditPro is the best solves all your love trouble and unclogs your drain”), consider making them off-topic. But if you can moderate them here, you will get better answers, because the questions will reach the best audience.

My advice is to allow software recommendations on GD, and enforce SR's quality guidelines.